# Swift/Math - Maintain origin when scaling

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, swift2

I have a scrollView with contentSize of (1300,800) and zoomScale of 1.0 and I have a UIView added to that scrollview with origin X: 600 Y: 400 the UIView sits on top of an UIImageView.

Now let's say I zoom out and the zoomScale is now at 0.9. I have placed the UIView at X: 600 and Y: 400 because it sits on top of a special place in the image when the image is in it's original size, but when I zoom out the image gets scaled and now X: 600 and Y: 400 isn't where the UIView should be placed. It should follow the resize of the image.

As you can see below the box sits in the place that I have positioned it. And this works as long as I don't change the size of the image, but when I zoom in the UIScrollView the image is being scaled, and the Origin X and Y don't fit any more.

How can I maintain X position and Y Position? So that when I scale the image the box changes it's X Position and Y Position to be seated in the same location at all times.

[image: Visualization]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this should be as easy as multiplying the x/y and width/height of your red box by the scale factor.

Comment: I tried this: 
var frame = airport.frame
frame.origin.x  = airport.frame.origin.x * mapView.zoomScale
frame.origin.y = airport.frame.origin.y * mapView.zoomScale
airport.frame = frame

But it didn't work.

Comment: It didn't change at all or did it change in a way that was not expected/desired?

Comment: It just went off to the side and off screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the UIView sits on top of an UIImageView

"Sit on top of" is not enough. Make the red view (the UIView) a *subview* of the map view (the UIImageView).

The scroll view zooms the map view by applying a scale transform to the map view, and that scale transform will apply to the map view's subview as well.

Comment: Yes this works as a solution, but what if i want to apply the same scale to the view without having it added to the UIImageView.

Comment: Then _pretend_ it's a subview. Seriously. Think about what I just said. What did we just learn? We learned that if it _were_ a subview, its size and position _wouldn't change_. So just keep calling `convertRect:fromView` for _the same rect_ of the map, to find out what that same rect now is in some other set of coordinates.